# How to create fixed background scrolling effect without background image?

Tags: css

I have a horizontally and vertically centred image on a page. I would like it so when the user scrolls down, the content below it actually comes up, as if the top content is fixed. Like this effect here... http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/02/fixed-background-scrolling-layout/

Only problem is for that effect they use the background-attachment: fixed property. I cannot use this as I need the image to be content (it will actually be changed to HTML5 video).

My code is here... http://jsfiddle.net/5jphd/1/

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg">
    <div class="text">Scroll down</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    Here is some content
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;      
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.text {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 20px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -44px;
}
.wrap {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Is this possible to do with this markup? So when you scroll down the content will rise up and overlap the image.

Comment: I'm kind of confused.. why not just use a fixed HTML5 video then? You would just make the content background transparent. *By the way*, a lot of computers will lag like crazy if you use HD HTML5 video backgrounds.. even a 5 second repeating clip is like 5mb and nearly crashes older PCs/Laptops and a lot of phones.

Comment: is this you are trying to achiev ? http://jsfiddle.net/5jphd/2/

Comment: Yes GCyrillus that is the result i am after, except the image has to be in the image tag, and not use a background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have done it, this is what I wanted to achieve. I simply made the video and scroll text position:fixed, and made the main body content position:relative - http://jsfiddle.net/5jphd/4/

```
html, body {height: 100%}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;      
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.text {
    position: fixed;    
    bottom: 20px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -44px;
}
.wrap {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    min-height: 1000px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jphd/3/)

I think this is what you're essentially asking for. Keep aspect ratios in mind, this is what an hd vieo would probably look like on a 320x480 or so.

```
#bg {
    position:absolute;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}
#bg img { max-width:100%; }
```